# Cassandra Multinode CentOs 6.5

Tags: cassandra, centos6.5

me and a partner have been trying to set up a simple multinode cluster on 4 servers. The servers are running Cent Os 6.5 and each had Cassandra 2.1.3 installed. We changed Cassandra.yaml as instructed in Datastax documentation, only to run nodetool status and find just the local instance listed as UN. We already opened the internode ports (7000,7001,7199) and nothing happens, the only anomaly I've found it's the fact that Host ID seems to repeat itself in each node. Any hints on what might be the problem?

Comment: 1) 2.1.3 is very old. If you're going to use 2.1, consider 2.1.12. You can also consider latest 2.2.x branch, but probably not 3+ unless this is just a test (don't use 3+ in production yet)

2) What seeds do you have set?

Comment: Apart from seed nodes configuration, you must also change `cassandra-rackdc.properties` files based on snitch you have set

Comment: We changed versions to 2.2.4. Trying to set up the nodes, but now we are getting an error about finding the System keyspace but not being able to load in. This is happening on the second node we try to run. Seed node did start up fine.

Comment: and probably disable selinux